# Nested loops or Cartezian product of arrays in Azure ARM

Tags: arrays, azure, nested-loops, azure-resource-manager, cartesian-product

I'm building an ARM(Azure Resource Manager) template to create multiple resources of the same type. Let's say metric alerts for SQL servers. I have:

1. 3 severity levels: [1, 2, 3]
2. 20 servers with names [sqlserver_1, sqlserver_2, ...]
3. 3 metrics to monitor [memory, cpu load, number of connections]

Essentially, I need a total of 180 resources. Is there any way how I can build and with all possible combinations of these variables. I.e. for each of the servers, I need to monitor 3 metrics where each could trigger 3 possible alerts levels depending on the metric levels.

Naturally, I thought about a Cartesian product of these arrays and then a `copy` loop over it to fill the template attributes. However, it doesn't look like ARM supports this.

Is it the point where instead of using ARM I should think about writing a code-generator to create a template instead of trying to bend ARM json?

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the issue, you can add the `copy` element to the resources section of your template. After doing that, you can dynamically set the number of resources to deploy. For more details, please refer to [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/copy-resources) and [here](https://dev.to/azure/demystifying-arm-templates-loops-46an).

For example

```
{
    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "parameters": {
        "org": {
            "type": "array",
            "defaultValue": [
                "contoso",
                "fabrikam",
                "coho"
            ]
        }
    },
    "resources": [
        {
            "apiVersion": "2017-06-01",
            "type": "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts",
            "name": "[concat(parameters('org')[copyIndex()], uniqueString(resourceGroup().id))]",
            "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
            "sku": {
                "name": "Standard_LRS"
            },
            "kind": "Storage",
            "properties": {},
            "copy": {
                "name": "storagecopy",
                "count": "[length(parameters('org'))]"
            }
        }
    ],
    "outputs": {}
}
```

Comment: Well, that will be a regular copy over one array.  What I'm looking for creating resources for each combination of values in 3 arrays.

Comment: @Vladimir You need is too complicated. It is not suitable for arm template. I suggest you use azure cli or powershell script. to implement it : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/alerts/alerts-metric